# Can't add Policy based QoS through Registry

Tags: registry, policy, qos

Im trying to "automate" the process of adding few policy based QoS in windows 7 at once.
When im entering "gpedit.msc" and creating a new policy, it ultimately creates a Registry key.
I tried to export those keys and running the .reg file in another computer. 
The keys are added to the Registry yet it is not added to GUI part at the gpedit.msc - which makes it useless, as it does not work with my program - making DSCP values to 0 again.
I tried tips from posts here - including the "QoSEnabled" key, which didnt work.
I would appriciate any help.

Comment: Welcome on SO, make sure to read the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: thanks, i did. hopefully would get some help